# Using IProfileService when sign-in by Google OAuth

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to change the IdentityServer4 AspNetIdentity sample to be able to login from both local created users and Google.

I was able to do this by adding Google authentication:

```
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        var cookieScheme = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Value.Cookies.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            SignInScheme = cookieScheme,
            ClientId = "client_id",
            ClientSecret = "client_secret"
        });
```

As expected the Home view shows correct user claims:

```
sub
c51da331-0348-45dd-352f-08d4526f6266
name
EMAIL@gmail.com
AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp
568a167f-a431-4f70-ba66-918f99e95eef
idp
Google
amr
external
auth_time
1486815555
```

When user signs in for the first time using Google account I add some information to the database and I thought I can add them to the user claims by using a custom IProfileService implementation and configuring IdentityServer to use my custom IProfileService:

```
         var builder = services.AddIdentityServer();
         builder.AddTemporarySigningCredential();

        builder.AddConfigurationStore(b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));
        builder.AddOperationalStore(b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));
        builder.AddAspNetIdentity<MyUser>();
        builder.AddProfileService<MyCustomProfileService>();
```

But now when I navigate to Home page the user claims remain the same and even GetProfileDataAsync method will not hit.

I appreciate if anyone can tell me what is it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the IdentityServer will not use IProfileService to add custom claims if it is configured to use ASP.NET Identity library unless (as mentioned by [@Set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177815/34623)) the UserInfo endpoint get called directly. The design approach is to use ASP.NET Identity mechanism for creating the claims by registering an [IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserclaimsprincipalfactory-1).

In this case we can either create a custom implementation of IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory or because ASP.NET Identity will load any additional claims stored in the database, add any extra claims using [AddClaimsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497521(v=vs.108).aspx) method of [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to discussion in [Adding Custom Claims to an ASPNET Core Identity Implementation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/574) on github, the `GetProfileDataAsync` method is only called if claims need to be put in a token. Also it has a link to [Optimizing Identity Tokens for size](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/14/optimizing-identity-tokens-for-size/) post that explains, that 
IdentityServer by default has behavior accordingly to OpenID Connect specification, that suggests the following (in section 5.4):

> The Claims requested by the profile, email, address, and phone scope values are returned from the UserInfo Endpoint, as described in Section 5.3.2, when a response_type value is used that results in an Access Token being issued. However, when no Access Token is issued (which is the case for the response_type value id_token), the resulting Claims are returned in the ID Token.

In other words, if only an identity token is requested, put all claims into the token. If however an access token is requested as well => remove the claims from the identity token and let the client use the userinfo endpoint to retrieve them.

However, it is possible to override this default behavior by setting the `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` flag on the Client configuration (more [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/528)).